# Update Panel Error

Tags: 2010, error, updatepanel

I am working with SharePoint 2010 features. I am writing feature receiver code  where I create new web part pages with ReportViewerWebPart and my custom web part on the page. I am creating multiple web part pages on feature activation. All the pages are created OK. But first time when I open such page I get the following error.

> "Cannot unregister UpdatePanel with ID 'ViewerAreaUpdatePanel' since
>   it was not registered     with the ScriptManager. This might occur if
>   the UpdatePanel was removed from the control tree and later added
>   again, which is not supported. Parameter name: updatePanel"

On refreshing the page this error fades and page loads but showing "1 item remaining" on status bar.

I would like to specify that I am creating SPConext before initialization of `ReportViewerWebPart` and after adding the reportviewer to page I reset the `HttpContext.Current` to its original value. without this `ReportViewerWebPart` can not be added dynamically. If this has something to do with the problem?

I am not using any update panels in my custom web part. Could you please help me getting rid of this problem.

Comment: Have you checked this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650218.aspx

Comment: I have run in to this exact problem. Did you ever figure this out?